# Writing file in external storage crashes android app

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I know of cours that here were some question about this, but I still can't find answer.
I need to write some text in external storage, but this code makes application crashed. Note that String dane is this text.

```
 void zapis2 (String dane){
        Context myContext = getApplicationContext();
        File file = new File(myContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), "state.txt");
        try {

             FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file, true); 
             OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                 out.write(dane);
             out.close();}catch (IOException e) {
                }
    }
```

Have you got any idea. I add permision in android manifest of course.

Comment: Do you have permission for writing? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: And where is stacktrace for error??

Comment: You have an empty catch block. Log the exception and see LogCat. That should reveal the exact nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/foldername");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename.txt");

try {
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
    pw.println(dane); //your string which you want to store
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    f.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is answer I needed! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`Contect.getExternalFilesDir(..)` is only available from [API8](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29), if you run/deploy on earler versions it will crash.

Comment: I use Android 2.2, so it's exactly this api